# Ubuntu Software will not install my VPN service

Tags: vpn

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Ubuntu Software installer will not install my paid VPN service. It says it is from a third party and may contain non-free components. Why will it not install what I pay for, I have used this same service in 14.04 with no problems at all.I have also tried to install with the terminal with no success. Any ideas on how to fix this??

Comment: Edit your question to include the full output from when you attempt to install it at the terminal and you will be more likely to receive assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay boys and girls this is how I fixed my problem. Install Ubuntu Software Center and use this to install any of your third party programs. It worked for me so I will keep using it. I know 16.04 is still brand spanking new, but there are bugs that should have been fixed before this. This is one of them, hope they can get it right it looks like it could be very useful.